# I need a help in custom mvc login page and dashboard display user details and pic MVC4

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I'm a student now I'm learning MVC4. I have designed a custom website in MVC and there is a custom user login form and Dashboard.

I have created a login filed with an Email and Password and a renumber me check box

after that I have code like this below

1. Models Code

   ```
   public class Login
               {
                   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter E-mail.")]
                   [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
                   [StringLength(150)]               
               public string Email { get; set; }
                 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Password.")]
                 [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                 [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 6)]
                 public string Password { get; set; }
               }
   ```
2. User Controller

   ```
   [HttpGet] public ActionResult Login()
   {
       return View();
   }
   #region Login Model
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Login(Models.MessageGroup.Login User)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           if (IsValid(User.Email, User.Password))
           {  
               FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.Email, false);
               return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "User");
           }
           else
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError("error", "Please check Login details are incorrect.");
           }
       }
       return View(User);
   }
   ```

but how can I display the user name and photo of the user in dashboard

in

```
 <img src="" alt="">
 <span class="username">User Full name</span>
```

if I check `@User.Identity.Name` that is coming up null also

here is my web.confg file also

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>        
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>    
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>   
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
<forms loginUrl="Login.cshtml" protection="All" timeout="30" name=".ASPXAUTH" 
 path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Index.cshtml"  
 cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" /> </authentication>
```

it will return `@User.Identity.Name`

Comment: its help to get login value in @User.Identity.Name which are not coming after with develop custom login

Answer (score 0):

If you have already enabled Identity it might have some configs in web.config that is something like  this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

you have to remve the line